# Logo custom width not implementing

Tags: php, functions, logo

```
add_theme_support( 'custom-logo', array(
        'height'      => auto,
        'width'       => 200,
        'flex-width' => true,
        'flex-height' => true,
    ) );
```

and

```
function theme_prefix_the_custom_logo() {
    if ( function_exists( 'the_custom_logo' ) ) {
    the_custom_logo();
    }
}
```

[Live link](http://html.trafficopedia.com/press/1/)

But it is not taking the custom `width` and `height` dimension.

Comment: Looks like it is taking the width and height atts on the link you provided

Comment: I don't see `the_custom_logo()` function and can't imagine what it does.